# Downloading a csv from a FTP server using apache camel

Tags: csv, ftp, apache-camel

I am trying to download a csv file from a FTP server using apache camel, i tried multiple approaches but have not been successful yet.

```
1) Approach 1 - Trying to just download a csv and store in local.

from("direct://start").

from("ftp://user@ftpserver/Directory?password=secret&download=true&fileName=a-b-c-2018-04-
16.csv")
   .to("file://dir")
```

Exception:  No type converter available to convert from type: 
  java.lang.Integer to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value -1

```
2) Approach 2 - Trying to unmarshal and save in a arrayBuffer 

 var result = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]

from("direct://start")
.from("ftp://user@ftpserver/Directory?password=secret&fileName=a-b-c-2018-
04-16.csv").unmarshal().csv().process(new Processor {
  override def process(exchange: Exchange): Unit = {
    val csvContent = exchange.getIn().getBody(classOf[String])
    result+=csvContent
   }
 })
  .to("file://dir")
```

I don't think it's running the processor itself here...
giving the same error as above..

Comment: Your route should start with the FTP consumer, not the `direct` consumer.

Comment: I tried that but got the following exception:-  Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://start. Exchange[ID-FA08CFDECF6B7-1525440391467-0-1]

Comment: Well yes, this exception says that nobody is listening on the direct endpoint you removed. You must not continue to send messages there.

Comment: I had a route trigger which was sending message to that end point, i removed it and did not get any error but i don't see any directory created ,in the console logs i can see that it has successfully created endpoints...

Comment: in the logs it says  ] DEBUG onent.file.GenericFileProducer - Starting producer: Producer[file://dir]
12:47:52.097 [main           ] DEBUG camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 >>> EventDrivenConsumerRoute[user@ftpserver/Directory?password=secret&download=true&fileName=a-b-c-2018-04-
16.csv&password=xxxxxx -> Channel[sendTo(file://dir)]]
12:47:52.097 [main           ] DEBUG camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Starting consumer (order: 1000) on route: route1
12:47:52.100 [main           ] DEBUG agement.Defa

Comment: 12:47:52.242 [main           ] INFO  camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: user@ftpserver/Directory?password=secret&download=true&fileName=a-b-c-2018-04-
16.csv&password=xxxxxx
12:47:52.243 [main           ] INFO  camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
12:47:52.244 [main           ] INFO  camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.568 seconds

Comment: i still don't see anything downloaded